# Getting weird character on my PHP/MySQL site

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, utf-8, character-encoding

On the title of the articles of my site, my site is converting apostrophe (`'`) to this:

```
�
```

Any idea why? My site is in Drupal and meta is as follows:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: Looks like a content-encoding issue. `<meta>` content-type headers are mostly ignored in favor of HTTP response headers. Make sure that that as well as the encoding of the database are both UTF-8.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Mike; how would I implement your suggestion?

Comment: With Drupal? No idea. Sorry.

Comment: With any PHP/MySQL site; I will politely ask Drupal to abide.

Comment: I've seen this before. It probably isn't doing this in all browsers. But to fix it in all browsers, use the HTML entity instead of '.

Comment: Send the content encoding with [header()](http://www.php.net/header), specifically sending something like `Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8`. Then check your database tables to make sure the `CHARACTER SET` is `utf8` (without the dash).

Comment: @Steve you can check the current headers being sent by the page with the [Web Developer extension](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=web+developer+toolbar&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) for Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: @developerwjk, I changed it the output as a parameter to htmlentities function. It does change but changes to `&#0`, any idea why?

Comment: @Mike, I checked the current headers; they are Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8. So I guess that is correct.

Comment: You can manually see and change the character set the browser reads your page in while viewing the page. In Firefox, this is in the View -> Character Set menu. (Press the left alt button on your keyboard to get the old menu bar in newer versions of Firefox that hide it.) You can use this to determine if it correctly sets UTF-8 and if so and it still doesn't display, what the *correct* character set would be (if any).

Comment: @Steve Check to see what your file itself is encoded as.